# Classloading Issue with server deployed persistence unit

Tags: java, classloader, wildfly

I'm having a problem in an EAR package which contains a server deployed persistence unit in an EJB mdule, and a web app in a WAR module

```
EAR
 |--- persistence unit (EJB module) 
 |--- web app (WAR)
 ...
```

Everything compiles and the deploy (under WildFly 10 CR5) is performed successfully. The persistnce unit is correctly deployed and the schema is created (using Hibernate schema generation during development).

Though, when I try to persist one of the entities like that

```
MyEntitiy e = new MyEntitiy();
e.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
e.setName("name");
entityService.save(e);
```

I get a runtime error which root cause is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field x.y.z.MyEntity.id to x.y.z.MyEntity
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
```

Diving into the debugger, I tracked down to the method `sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj` which perform a check via the method `Class.isAssignableFrom` between the classes

1. the class of the `Field` object (`Field.getDeclaredClass()`)
2. the class of the entity to be persisted

This check returns false, due to the fact that the to classes have been loaded with different `ClassLoader`s (they are logically the same class).

How can I overcome this issue without changing the general layuot of the project (ie, keep the persistence unit as an EJB module to be shared across various modules)?

Comment: Are you packaging MyEntity class(or entities) in both ejb jar and the war file as well?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu yes

Comment: Although I have not tested it, per jboss docs, you may want to remove domain entities from war file and test. As per docs, classes defined in ejb jar are available for classes in war file by default.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu hi! Took a while before I could thourroughly test your solution out (had to rewrite part of the core code to do so). It works: if you want to put an answer to the question, I'll be glad to accept it roght away.

Comment: Glad that has helped. I have posted it as an answer so that others can also benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you might have included MyEntity class(or entities) in both ejb jar and war file and so they are getting loaded by both the class loaders. You may need to remove domain entities from war file and test it.

As per jboss docs, classes defined in ejb jar are available for classes in war file by default. And so they will loaded only once by ejb classloader only and will be used/available for classes in the war file as well.